# Connecting Advantage Database in Java

Tags: java, netbeans-8, advantage-database-server

excuse me guys, but I'm a total beginner.

I want to know how to connect to an Advantage Database in Java. I'm using NetBeans. I downloaded the Advantage JDBC and added the JAR file in my project's Libraries. I'm not sure what to do next. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows users only**

**Pre-Requisites:**

jdk1.6.0_11
Advantage Database Server 9.1
adsjdbc.jar
Advantage Database Server

**Environment Variables:**

Enter Variable name and Variable value which is mentioned below.

Variable name:

CLASSPATH

Variable value:

.;C:\ADSDriver\lib\adsjdbc.jar

**Program to connect Java with ADS**

```
 public class ConnectADS {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Connection connection = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            Statement statement = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262;catalog=C:\\yourDatbase\\data;TableType=cdx;LockType=proprietary", "AdsSys", "no");
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                resultSet = statement
                        .executeQuery("SELECT EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEEDETAILS");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NAME:"
                            + resultSet.getString("EMPNAME"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get: com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSException: [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage JDBC]Connection refused: connect
 at com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.n.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 at test.ConnectADS.main(ConnectADS.java:15)
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.ConnectADS.main(ConnectADS.java:28)